# Cordova:Unable to build project with corodva-plugin-calendar

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm developing the cordova application, in which I want to have some kind of booking functionality through calendar. So for that, I installed very famous [EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin) plugin.

But while building the project, it's throwing following error

```
/home/admin/Desktop/myApp/platforms/android/src/nl/xservices/plugins/Calendar.java:148: error: cannot find symbol
      if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED != ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.cordova.getActivity(), type)) {
                                                            ^
  symbol:   method checkSelfPermission(Activity,String)
  location: class ContextCompat
/home/admin/Desktop/myApp/platforms/android/src/nl/xservices/plugins/Calendar.java:157: error: cannot find symbol
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    ^
  symbol:   method requestPermissions(Activity,String[],int)
  location: class ActivityCompat
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 43.228 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/admin/Desktop/myApp/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/admin/Desktop/myApp/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=x86,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

I also gone through following threads..but still no help

1. [Android M (6) compatibility](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/255)
2. [Issue related to the new Cordova version CLI >5](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/265)

**My Environment**

1. Cordova-CLI : 6.1.1
2. Android-Sdk : 23

So, what should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, kindly help us.

Comment: @pac-man though i m not an expert in android, looking at the plugin's android source code, i believe this issue is something to do with android-support-v4.jar path as ContextCompat and ActivityCompat class are part of this jar and it is not able to be located during the build as per your error trace. Hope it provides some pointer.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after updating my plugins. To save time, I just used an older version of the plugin.

`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-calendar@4.4.4`

Comment: Hey mate.. you really save my day.. I've been trying a lot of things and this was the only solution... it seems 4.4.7 it not working properly... at least on my environment.
Thanks